# Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string is deprecated in CodeIgniter 4 (PHP 8)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make date difference (in days) between today and a date from a field in database (array), this is my code :

```
$date1 = date_create ($v['sipp_ed']);//this is from field in database
$date2 = new DateTime();
$intval = date_diff ($date1, $date2);
echo $intval->format("Diiference is %a days");
```

but always get error "Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string is deprecated". I have tried many times with other functions like strtotime, date, and  getdate, but always fail.....could anybody help me, please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On this line

```php
$date1 = date_create ($v['sipp_ed']);
```

It's telling you that `$v['sipp_ed']` is **null**.

Either check its value or use something like this which will pass an empty string when the value is null.

```php
$date1 = date_create ($v['sipp_ed'] ?? '');
```

Comment: No, it is not null....this is the value when I print the value (dd($date1);) where $date1 = date_create ($v['sipp_ed'] ?? ''); , like your suggestion.. : $date1 DateTime (3) 2018-07-31 00:00:00-05:00 CDT.

Comment: Does it work with that change

Comment: Yes, it works, but when I try to take the difference : if ($intval>=90) {
                                                            $hari="Kadaluarsa";
                                                        } it doesn't work > "Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int "

Comment: Since it works you should **tick the answer**.  I have upvoted the question.  It doesn't work because $intval is an object, not an integer.  See [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).  You either need to convert $intval to integer or 90 to datetime.   You need to start googling for php examples.  Start with "php datetime object"

Comment: What do you mean **tick the answer**...I am a new member, don't know the rules.....but thanks for the answer....I will googling for  "php datetime object".